# Widget appears wrong using Mac OS Safari and suddenly changes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

A Flutter WebApp behaves using MacOS Chrome just fine. Using Safari on MacOS, the UI changes at certain points randomly. MacOS and Safari are the most recent releases with any applicable patch installed.

As far as I understand, MacOS Safari is a first class platform to run Flutter apps.
**Could someone explain, what I may have missed?**

**Example**

- The Widget should appear as in the right image.
- Actually, it appears as the one in the left image.
- As soon as I move the mouse pointer over the second button, it changes from `Urlau` to `...`.

The String `Urlau` appears somewhere in the Flutter app, but very far away from the respective widget. Fully unrelated.

I compiled like so: `flutter build web --web-renderer html`

**Using Safari on MacOS appears like so:**

[image]

**Using Chrome on MacOS appears just fine:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rendering with canvas kit using this command

```dart
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```

Comment: Here too, the documentation doesn't explain not to use the HTML renderer. Just explains, that two alternatives exist. https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/renderers

Comment: Yeah if you do just flutter build web it will render using html in desktop and canvaskit on mobile devices. But we also have the option to force the renderer to use html or canvas kit. Html renderer works good on chrome. Safari has some issues which works well on canvas kit.. just by personal experience. Not sure why.

Comment: Ah, OK. If I use auto, the compiled app decides which version to download to the browser? OK, I read it as if I tell the compiler to compile for html or canvaskit - and not both. Thank you again, Kaushik!

Comment: Appears to work fine. Need to test a bit more. Interesting side effect: Text now appears much sharper than compiled using the HTML option. Only some text appeared using html blurry, other text appeared perfectly sharp.

Comment: Exactly. Choosing the renderer depends on the requirement

Comment: So unless download size is very critical, this is the best way to compile:: flutter build web --release

Comment: Not exactly. For example sometimes you may use some packages which would need html renderer explicitly. Like pointer interceptor